# successful os x 10.6 install? anyone?

Tags: ros, macos-snowleopard, 64bit, rosinstall, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a brand new 64bit macbook pro with os x 10.6.  I am wondering if anyone has successfully installed the bare bones version of ros with a similar setup?  Is there any initiative to get a package based installer?

I went through the tutorial for installing and poked around some forums for answers to bugs, but at this point I have been watching macports try and build atlas for about 2 hours.

Is there a non-macports based installation for os x 10.6?  I am curious if anyone has even got it running/has a personal walk through on the setup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10226/successful-os-x-10.6-install?-anyone?/) by [Chocobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/676/chocobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-06-13**:
You probably just have to wait the atlas package out.  It took the better part of an evening to get everything installed on 10.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed diamondback from source on my MacBook Pro (10.6.7) following the [installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/OSX).

It worked fine for me.  I've built  the `ros`, `ros_comm`, and `ros_tutorials` stacks, as well as some others.  Depending on how much of MacPorts you have installed, it can take quite a long time to build the system dependencies (e.g., at some point you might be building gcc4.4).  You just have to wait it out.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on writing up a detailed process for 10.6 as soon as we get it running. I'll post the link as soon as I get it up! In the mean time, I haven't come up with a good way to do it without macports. Some things like atlas and gcc44 are huge and took us a long time to get built. Just let it run

---

Originally posted by [Perchik](https://answers.ros.org/users/643/perchik/) with karma: 13 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1